# Connect two networks with different subnets

Tags: networking, router, lan, dhcp, windows-server-2012

The ISP cable is connected to a Netgear router (main router, DHCP enabled). From this router goes out two cables, one for a server with static IP 192.168.1.3 (Windows Server 2012, with 2 NICs) and another to a wireless router (configured as switch with DHCP disabled).

From the server, in the second NIC, goes out a cable to a switch where is connected several computers, with static IP 192.168.2.2 and DHCP enabled. So, every computer here has 192.168.2.X IP number.

In the wireless router, there are few computers via LAN and others over wifi, getting IPs from main router in range 192.168.1.100 to 192.168.1.150

How can I do to make the computers to look each other.

Below is a image how network is connected.

Thanks in advance for your help.

[image]

Comment: The simplest solution is to make everything one network by Either defining it as `192.168.x.x/16`.

Comment: this will be more difficult as its currently configured because of the SOHO class hardware (the TPLink and the Netgear). usually its difficult to make gateway routers function well as interior routers. you can't just turn off nat and the statefull firewall easily. if you routers and firewalls are correctly configured and allow the traffic, its simply a matter of distributing routes for the remote subnet to the clients and routers.

Answer (score 0):

On the Netgear router, add a static route for 192.168.2.0 Network and point it to the Windows Server NIC 1: 192.168.1.3

On the Windows Server, you will need to enable RRAS (Routing and Remote Access). Enable LAN Routing.

Here is a link for setting up LAN routing on 2016. Server 2012 should be similar.

[https://protechgurus.com/configure-lan-routing-windows-server-2016/#:~:text=To%20install%20the%20LAN%20Routing,role%20and%20then%20click%20Next](https://protechgurus.com/configure-lan-routing-windows-server-2016/#:%7E:text=To%20install%20the%20LAN%20Routing,role%20and%20then%20click%20Next).

Comment: Hello. Thank you for your reply. I tried to do as you said, but it didn't worked (I don't know if I didn't configured it properly). In the Netgear I went to "Static routes" and set the route to 192.168.2.0 network as destination and NIC address 192.168.1.3 as gateway IP.

Comment: The problem now is to configure LAN routing in the server. RRAS is already configured in the server with several options (done for another person in the past). I don't know how to check is LAN routing is enabled. If I try to configure it, a popup message says I can't without disabling configuration and starting again. Is there a way to check if it's enabled? I found the code `Set-NetIPInterface -Forwarding Enabled` to execute in PowerShell for activating LAN routing and I did it, but still nothing works.

Comment: Start Routing and Remote Access MMC.
Right Click on the Server Name and click on Properties.
In General Tab, you will see if the server is configured for LAN Routing.

Comment: I checked in the server and LAN Routing is enabled. What could be the problem that any request from 192.168.2.X to 192.168.1.X can be done but not in reverse?